# Linux While True Loop Inside of a Screen to Monitor Another Screen Process

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to working with screens in Linux and I am trying to figure out how to create a screen that will execute a while true loop every 15 seconds that will monitor another screen process that I have called "myserver".

My idea was to use the following:

```
screen -dmS myservermonitor bash -c \
  'while true; do
     if ! screen -list | grep -q "myserver"; then
       screen -S myserver java \
              @user_jvm_args.txt \
              @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.18.2-40.2.10/unix_args.txt \
              "$@"
     fi
     sleep 15
   done'
```

With the thought being that it would create a screen called "myservermonitor" that will then check if the "myserver" screen is alive and if it is not it will create it, and if it is then it would wait 15 seconds and run another check to see if it is alive once more. However, this is not working as it just creates a dead process called "myservermonitor". Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can't say for sure if this is your problem, but `grep -q myserver` will also match `myservermonitor`, right? I would take `screen` out of the picture until you understand better what is going on (use plain xterms). Also, please consider wrapping your code in your question so it is visible without having to scrolll right. To make it so readers can copy/paste, use the "\" (backslash only, no quotes needed) as the line-continuation character. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like XY-problem. Do you want to simply restart something if it crashed? Run your server as a systemd service. Configure it to restart on crash. Systemd will do the job.

Comment: @tjordan I edited your code so that the `bash -c` script is a multi-line argument, for readability. Can you check it?